# Is there a simple 'is_authenticated' solution in Stormpath?

Tags: flask-login, stormpath

I found this in the Stormpath docs:

```
is_authenticated() (http://flask-stormpath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html)
All users will always be authenticated, so this will always return True.
```

So is_authenticated does not seem to work as it does in flask-login. Do I have to do a workaround or is there a similar function already pre-buildt in this API?

---EDIT---

Thanks for the answer, but it still does not seem to work. What I am trying to do is this:

**navbar.html**

```
<div class="navbar-right">
    {% if user %}
    <p class="navbar-text">Signed in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">{{ result }}</a></p>
    {% else %}
    <button id="registerbtn" type="button" class="btn btn-default navbar-btn">Sign up</button>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

**app.py**

```
@app.route('/navbar')
    def navbar():
    if user:
        return render_template('navbar.html', result=user.given_name)
    else:
        return render_template('navbar.html')
```

And I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'given_name'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this error as well. I used similar code as that provided above:

```
if user:
     return render_template('index.html', given_name=user.given_name)
return render_template('index.html')
```

and would get the same error as in OP:

```
AttributeError: 'AnonymousUserMixin' object has no attribute 'given_name'
```

I fixed it by changing the code to:

```
if user.is_anonymous() == False:
    return render_template('index.html', given_name=user.given_name)
return render_template('index.html')
```

It seems that the error was that the if statement for the user object always resolves as True because the user object is instantiated in some way when importing user from flask.ext.stormpath.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of this library. There is indeed a way to check whether or not a user is authenticated -- the code you found is actually part of the internal Flask-Login API, and not meant for public consumption.

What you want to do is this:

```
from flask_stormpath import user

def my_view():
    if user:
        # there is a user who is authenticated!
    else:
        # nobody has authenticated :(
```

That'll get you what you want =)

Comment: Still does not seem to work, I updated my question - maybe you can help me out once again. :)

Comment: Are you using some other plugin other than Flask-Stormpath? Looking at your updated question, it appears you've got something else overwriting that `user` object.

Comment: No, no other plugin than Flask-Stormpath in this application.